# Is it possible to use mysql_insert_id() with a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($eventchoices)) {

 echo $row['res_name']. " and " .$row['event_name']; 
 echo "<br>";

}
```

Would like to get the last inserted row to be shown, this currently gets everything in the array, I tried to use `mysql_insert_id()`  like so `mysql_insert_id($row);` and other methods like using it inside the while loop all attempts come back with errors.

your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` is [*deprecated*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). Please use `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Comment: By "deprecated" @alfasin means may set your house on fire, eat your children, or cause sudden job loss when your entire database is leaked to Anonymous because of a [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: @tadman, here we meet again :) You see, our last encounter effected me so much that I joined the "anti `mysql_` squad"...

Comment: Glad to see there's some momentum here. Some of the code I see posted here is so full of holes that something needs to be done to promote safe use of SQL.

Answer (score 3):

[`mysql_insert_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) only works when *inserting* records into a table (with an AUTO INCREMENT column). It does not get the ID of the row with SELECT statements. You have to do that in your query.

FYI, mysql_* functions should not be used for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: It's shocking that so many people pick up `mysql_query` as the first thing. I think that in the next version of PHP those should be *disabled* by default. Though, predictably, questions on StackOverflow would then be about how to turn it back on. Small steps are important, though.